# CoolShip "Computer in a keyboard" for Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

I am about to receive an Indiegogo crowd-source funded "artesinal" Android 4.0 computer in-a-keyboard, called "CoolShip".  How can I run Ubuntu on this new A-9 Dual-core +Quad-core low-cost desktop?  ROM'S and firmware are removeable and replaceable with factory boards with a lifetime free replacement guarantee.    http://www.focuswill.com/html_info/CoolShip-6.html. Looks like a good mix as a cheap Ubuntu Linux platform: $89-139.

Comment: I am going to try installing Picuntu (for the MK808, but they have the same Soc). I expect it will work. I'll report back. FocusWill has also said that they will be working on a Linux distro of some kind.

Comment: @user21572 Did you have any luck? If so, how? Thanks!

Comment: No, and I later found out that I am one of the very few that actually received the hardware. The guy and the company are gone. There's no one to ask, and the interface isn't the same as on an MK808, so I can't just Flash Picuntu. Sorry.